# How can I loop over each row in R and see if a condition is met to change the format of a date?

Tags: r, loops, date, format

I have two dataframes A and B

A has dates formatted yyyy-mm-dd

B has dates formatted mm/dd/yyyy

Note that B has a mix of dates and the word 'control' since not all of the dates 
are populated (some are controls for this study and don't have dates)

I need the dates of B to look like A so that in another part of what I'm doing match where the dates are equal and since they aren't in the same format I cannot equate them.

I tried saying things like if date != 'control' then format the date, or doing a for loop for each row, but I can't get anything to work.

How should I approach this?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

We can automatically format the dates in both dataset to `Date` class with `anydate`

```
library(anytime)
A$date <- anydate(A$date)
B$date <- anydate(B$date)
```

---

Or in `base R`, we can use the correct `format`

```
A$date <- as.Date(A$date, format = "%Y-%m-%d")
B$date <- as.Date(B$date, format = "%m/%d/%Y")
```

Note that if there are any value that is not the standard date format i.e. any string, it would result in `NA` for that element.  Then we can use `is.na` to filter out those values or change it

---

If we want to subset the data by excluding the rows with 'control'

```
i1 <- A$date != 'control'
as.Date(A$date[i1], format = "%Y-%m-%d")
```

Similarly can subset the 'B', but this is not really needed as `NA` is more easier to manipulate

Comment: i can't do as.date because some of the rows say 'control' and aren't a date so it'll error. i think i'd need to loop through each

Comment: @Love It won't result in error, just give `NA` i.e. `as.Date(c("2019-05-01", "control"))#
[1] "2019-05-01" NA` and then you can remove the NA or create a logical output with `is.na`